# should I use "should" when talking about grammar rules?

Tags: word-usage

Consider these

> Wh-questions **begin with** what, when, where, who, whom, which, whose, why and how.
>
> Wh-questions **should begin with** what, when, where, who, whom, which, whose, why and how.

The former comes from the [Cambridge Dictionary grammar tutorial](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions). I put an "should" to construct the latter.

Does the latter implicate some kind of compulsion or forcefulness and therefore is rarely used when talking about grammar rules?

Comment: Both are okay. There is nothing to ponder over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, adding **should** doesn't indicate compulsion or forcefulness. What is does is introduce a doubt about the bare statement of fact in the first example.

It's as if you were saying, "WH-questions **should** begin with..., but sometimes they do not."

Comment: What about a sentence like "_A house with two floors **should** have at least two bathrooms_"? It doesn't seem like there's any doubt introduced there -- sure, it doesn't indicate compulsion, but it does indicate that the speaker believes something along those lines.

Comment: @Kman3 I think your example is different, because the house doesn't exist yet. "Should" there is a prescription about how to build the house. If you said it of an existing house, "The house has two floors, and should have two bathrooms...", it would certainly introduce doubt.

Comment: There's no particular house -- it's talking about houses with two floors in general. The sentence serves to indicate the speaker's opinion on what _should_ be in a two-storey house. It has the same sense as "ought to". The speaker wouldn't have that opinion if they had doubt about it.

Comment: @Kman3 Compare it to the statement "Houses with two floors have two bathrooms." Now insert "should". It introduces the possibility that some two-floor houses may not.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The first statement is assertive, and the second statement is the speaker presenting their opinion assertively.

Comment: @Kman3 Does too. The first statement is a statement of fact. The second is, as you admit, an opinion.

Comment: An opinion presented **assertively**. A speaker has no doubt of their opinion when they present it assertively. "_Should_" has multiple meanings. If it has the sole meaning that you describe, then the sentences "I **should** head home" and "This computer **should** work" use it in the same sense, when they do _not_.

Comment: @Kman3 Alright, You have a good day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108438/discussion-between-kman3-and-jack-oflaherty).

Comment: @Kman3 I don't see the point. I have nothing to add.